# How to disallow service api and multilingual urls in robots.txt

Tags: seo, robots.txt

I need to disallow the next URLs:

1. service api `/_s/user`, `/_s/place`, ... All starts with `/_s/`
2. save form: `/{language}/save`. For example `/{en}/save`, `/{ru}/save`, ...

NOTE: most URLs have language parameter at the beginning: `/en/event`, ... I don't want to block them.

Should be something like: (but this is not allowed by `robots.txt` format)

```
Disallow: /_s/*
Disallow: /:lang/save
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

In `robots.txt` matching is from the left, so it matches anything that begins with `/pattern`.

The wildcard like `/*pattern` matches any beginning which must be followed by the given `pattern`. Therefore `*` is never needed on the right (e.g. `/foo*` as it is equivalent to `/foo`).

So in your case you can use

> `Disallow: /_s/`

- to disallow anything which starts with `/_s/` e.g. `/_s/foo`

> `Disallow: /*save`

- to disallow all patterns such as `/en/save` but **also** `/foosave` or `/en/save/other`

You can use `$` to signify "*must end with*"

> `Disallow: /*save$`

- to disallow all patterns such as `/en/save` or `/fr/save` but **not** `/en/save/other`

You can find a bit more on robots.txt in [Robots.txt : 4 Things You Should Know](http://www.searchenginejournal.com/robotstxt-4-things-you-should-know/7292/) article

I hope that will help.