# Robots.txt: disallow a folder's name, regardless at which depth it may show up

Tags: web-services, robots.txt

So I have to disallow search engines from indexing our REST web service responses (it's a Sitecore website); all of them have the same name in the URL but show up at different levels in the server hierarchy, and I was wondering if I can write a "catch all" entry in our robots file or if I am doomed to write an extensive list.

Can I add something like

```
Disallow: */ajax/*
```

to catch all folders named "ajax" regardless of where they appear?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`robots.txt` specification doesn't say anything about wildcards but Google ([Google Robots.txt Specifications](https://developers.google.com/webmasters/control-crawl-index/docs/robots_txt)) and Bing allow the use of wildcards in robots.txt files.

```
Disallow: */ajax/*
```

Your `disallow` is valid for all the `/ajax/` urls no matter what is the nesting level of `/ajax/`.

Comment: I see. Since matching is on the left, wouldn't

    */ajax/

be equivalent?

Comment: `*/ajax/` should be enough. You might want to check it using e.g. https://www.google.com/webmasters/tools/robots-testing-tool?pli=1

Answer (score 1):

You should be able to just use `Disallow: /*ajax`. Similar question over here:
[How to disallow service api and multilingual urls in robots.txt](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14608160/how-to-disallow-service-api-and-multilingual-urls-in-robots-txt)

Comment: This will not just block the /ajax/ directory it will also block **anything** that contains the word "ajax", e.g. http://example.com/blog/13572/top-ten-reasons-you-should-use-ajax