# Using robots.txt to stop weird indexing in Joomla

Tags: joomla, web-crawler, robots.txt

I use Joomla and have been seeing some really weird link variations being indexed. I've investigated it quite thoroughly and haven't yet found the cause, but it appears to be related to category names and ID's.

Regardless, I am attempting to workaround the issue by blocking the category names and ID's in robots.txt. The problem is that, despite my best efforts, I can't seem to create the appropriate disallow rule. I've tried countless variations and each time the Google robots.txt tester tells me that the URL is still "allowed".

An example of one of the category names and ID's is: *64-service-area*

I find this particular category and ID in all kinds of URL's like this one: */locations/north-dakota/64-service-area/hawaii/64-news*

Does anyone have advice as to how I can specifically block URL's with 64-service-area?

Comment: Possible duplicate: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31137082/robots-txt-disallow-a-folders-name-regardless-at-which-depth-it-may-show-up/31137499

Comment: Is service area a category and does it have id 64? Or is it that somehow it's getting the 64 twice?

Comment: Great question. "Service Area" is a parent category with a lot of children categories. The id 64 does not belong to 'Service Area' itself but to a child category under 'Service Area'. The id 64 is actually assigned to the category "Hawaii" which is a child of service area. But it's not just Hawaii and id 64, I often find the category 'Service Area' being indexed with any number of other, subcategory id's. Ironically, none of the categories are set to be crawled, they all explicitly have a 'no index, no follow' attribute.

Comment: Typically, weird indexing is caused by duplicate menu items on your website. Check your menus and make sure you always use menu aliases whenever you can.

Answer (score 0):

Bing and Google allow wildcards * ? (from https://youtu.be/G29Zt-UH_Ko).

You could try:

```
disallow: /locations/north-dakota/64-service-area/*
```